# Cannot pass variables to glob function

Tags: php, glob

I have been trying to pass 2 variables to a glob pattern. I have tried using a plain String first which works like a charm. Replacing parts of that String with variables makes it fail.

So in short:

```
glob("/home/plesk/remote_data/2016 06 09 16/Arena Cam 1 - /16 05 03*.jp2")
```

works perfectly.

When I replace parts of the path with variables, meaning

```
glob("/home/plesk/remote_data/". $currentDate ."/Arena Cam 1 - /". $currentTime ."*.jp2")
```

it returns an empty Array.

Also, when I put the argument in a variable, meaning creating

```
$arg ="/home/plesk/remote_data/2016 06 09 16/Arena Cam 1 - /16 05 03*.jp2")
```

and calling `glob($arg)`, it returns an empty Array.

Why is this happening and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short the string concatenation is wrong. Remember in a double quotes string literal `$values` are automatically expanded

Doing

```
glob("/home/plesk/remote_data/$currentDate/Arena Cam 1 - /$currentTime*.jp2")
```

Removes all the complexity and will probably work for you, assuming I have not added or removed spaces in my edit accidentally

I just thought, your problem may of course be related to the way you build your date and time into `$currentDate` and `$currentTime`. Maybe you should check that the date is being generated in the correct format!

Comment: Ah, I just checked. Seems like something is off about the current time I used.